# Сортировка в массив по датам

Tags: массивы, vb.net

У меня есть класс

```
Public Class EndCL
Public Property [date] As Date
Public Property goods_name As String
Public Property count As Decimal
Public Property price As Decimal
Public Property sum As Decimal
Public Property cash As Decimal
Public Property cashless As Decimal
End Class
```

в нем хранятся чеки 
помогите понять как отсортировать их по датам, то есть на выходе чтобы получился массив из которого я мог брать отдельно за определенный день или месяц

Comment: чтобы примерно вот так 'array{"30.06.2015" => чек,чек,чек;"31.06.2015" => чек,чек,чек}'

Comment: *в нем хранятся чеки* В каком свойстве класса они хранятся?